# plt.show() not working graph on ubuntu cmd promt

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, matplotlib, cmd

I am trying to learn machine learning using python and trying to get graphs to show using matplotlib. However when I run code showing the graph, it doesn't do anything. I am using the ubuntu terminal within windows cmd.

I am running through the tutorial within the tensorflow documentation
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

I know that using pycharm and running the code would show it, but i prefer to run and compile everything through the windows cmd, specifically the ubuntu terminal.

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(train_images[0])
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

When i run the code nothing happens. I tried to print() it but it prints None. I'm assuming it has something to do with the privileges set up with the ubuntu terminal but i have no clue how to fix it. Do I just have to use pycharm or is there a way to get this working?

Comment: Unfortunately, a Windows CMD doesn't support plotting operations unless it has Ipython, Which can be quite tedious to install if you're just starting. I suggest installing anaconda (A virtual environment manager) and either use Jupyter notebooks or Spyder

Comment: IMO your terminology needs a brush up, there neither is an `Ubuntu cmd prompt` nor an `ubuntu terminal within windows cmd`. Do you refer to WSL aka `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows` which runs in a Windows console?

Answer (score 0):

Install anaconda or conda and use Jupyter notebook. For purpose of learning, I see no reason to do plotting in that way.